# php regular expressions for substring start with A, end with B in order to remove the A and B

Tags: php, regex

I want to use regular expressions to find a substring that start with A and end with B and remove the A and B.

For example change `xxxxAmmmm(andMoreContentHere)Bvv` to

`xxxxmmmm(and something more)vv`.

This is what I come up with  `'/(A([^B]*)B)/i'`;

But using `preg_replace('/(A([^B]*)B)/i', '', $string)` will give me `xxxxvv` unless I specify `mmmm(andMoreContentHere)` but `(andMoreContentHere)` is user-generated content. So what should I do to only remove A and B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$str = 'xxxxAmmmm(andMoreContentHere)Bvv';
$str = preg_replace('/(A([^B]*)B)/', '\2', $str);
```

echo's

```
xxxxmmmm(andMoreContentHere)vv
```

Comment: The \2 backreferences the second paranthesis and uses it as the replace value.

Comment: Be careful with that "i" option... it will make your regex case insensitive, and if you are expecting an uppercase "A" and "B", get rid of that "i" option.

Comment: What if I want to find a substring that does not contain C but start with A and B? I know doesn't contain in RegExp is (?! C) but I don't know how to add it into /A([^B]*)B/i. Thanks!

Comment: love, You'd do /A([^BC]*)B/. [^...] matches "Any character but ..."

Comment: @AronCederholm Oh thanks so much! But what if it isn't a single char but a string (let's say Cat)?

Comment: Then I would recommend studying the negative lookahead (?!...). /A(((?!Cat)[^B])*)B/ will transform xxxxAmmmm(andMoreContentHere)Bvv to xxxxmmmm(andMoreContentHere)vv, but it will leave xxxxAmmmm(andMoreCatContentHere)Bvv as xxxxAmmmm(andMoreCatContentHere)Bvv

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$test = 'xxxxAmmmm(andMoreContentHere)Bvv';
$regex = '/A([^B]+)B/i';

echo preg_replace($regex, '$1', $test);
```

Output:

```
xxxxmmmm(andMoreContentHere)vv
```